# Can you preview Office 2010 files in Outlook 2013?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-outlook-2013, attachments, preview

**Issue:**

- One of our users is using Outlook 2013 and Excel 2010 on a Windows 7 machine. When she receives an email with an Excel file attached, she is unable to preview the Excel file. She gets this error: *"This file cannot be previewed because of an error with the following previewer:
  Microsoft Excel previewer
  To open this file in its own program, double-click it."*
- Is it possible to use the previewer for different versions of Microsoft Office? In this scenario, is it possible to preview Excel 2010 files in Outlook 2013?

**Workaround**

- Upgrading to Excel 2013 resolves the issue, but the user would prefer to stay on Excel 2010.

**Troubleshooting**

- The user is able to open the attachment in Excel 2010 by double-clicking on it
- In Outlook --> File --> Options --> Trust Center --> Trust Center Settings... --> Attachment Handling --> "Turn off Attachment Preview" is unchecked
- *Following the same path as in the previous step* --> Attachment Handling --> Attachment and Document Previewers... --> "Microsoft Excel previewer" is checked
- redgedit.exe --> HKLM \ Software \ Microsoft \ Windows \ Current Version \ PreviewHandlers --> the value for "Microsoft Excel previewer is set to "{00020827-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}"

Comment: No;  This has to do with the way the preview capability was written.

Comment: Hi Ramhound, thanks for the quick reply. Do you mean that this is written within the code that makes up Outlook's preview capability? Can this be changed by anyone but the developers?

Comment: +1 for well written question. Lots of background information provided and what was already attempted.

Comment: How do I choose Ramhound's answer as the best answer? I don't see a green check mark.

Comment: @Bahklava his wasn't an answer, but rather a comment on your question

Answer (score 0):

No. This has to do with the way the preview capability was written, [as explained by Rahmound](https://superuser.com/questions/823154/can-you-preview-office-2010-files-in-outlook-2013#comment1079771_823154)